# Como colocar un indicador de cargando en un RecyclerView en Android

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Tengo una duda sobre como agregar una "Vista" que indique que mi RecyclerView esta cargando los datos, mi idea es colocar una vista mientras mi RecyclerView esta cargando y no mostrar una pantalla en blanco, quiero implementar algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba intentando usar un ViewStup, pero no se con certeza si esto me ayude con mi objetivo, como podria recrear ese efecto de que se muestre una vista en lo que carga mi RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la forma de hacer ese efecto, tenia que usar el efecto Shimmer de facebook.

Primero en el gradle colocamos esta linea en la dependencias:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
```

Ya que colocamos esa linea tenemos que colocar en la vista donde tenemos nuestro recyclerview agregmos esto.

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />
            <include layout="@layout/shimmer_fragment_home" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Lo ultimo es hacer una copia de tu layout donde tienes tus CardViews y a todos tus elementos colocales un fondo background gris:

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/carta"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo_post"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/shimmer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagen_noticia"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vista_previa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagen_noticia"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titulo_post" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fecha_post"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@color/shimmer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagen_noticia"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vista_previa" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen_noticia"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/shimmer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Por ultimo en tu vista donde cargas tu recyclerview solo agregas estas lineas de código en el onCreateView:

```
shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.preview);
```

Y estas lineas van cuando termine de consultar la informacion o tu arreglo de datos:

```
shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```